# Regular expression trouble

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to get a regular expression to work but I'm struggling due to my lack of experience with them. The idea is to scan for particular strings that begin with 'GB:'

For example it should detect:

- GB:AB12ABC
- GB:AB34 ABC

But not:

- US:AB12ABC
- AB12ABC

I have this regular expression that matches the strings I'm looking for (takes into account different spaces, formats etc):

`/^([A-Z]{3}\s?(\d{3}|\d{2}|d{1})\s?[A-Z])|([A-Z]\s?(\d{3}|\d{2}|\d{1})\s?[A-Z]{3})|(([A-HK-PRSVWY][A-HJ-PR-Y])\s?([0][2-9]|[1-9][0-9])\s?[A-HJ-PR-Z]{3})$/`

But now I want to add the GB: bit on the front. What would I alter in the expression above to do this?

Comment: Just a tip: when asking regexp questions, it can help to add a tag to the programming language and/or regexp flavor you're using.

Comment: to just scan for them, use `grep '^GB' input`. What with the horrible construct above?

Comment: @Frederik If you have a better regex that accounts for the spacing, put it as an answer, you will probably be marked the solution for it.

Comment: In what context are you using this? sed, grep, awk, php, bash, or something else?

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys. Good tip with the tag as well. I'll be using it in PHP, and it's for detecting UK based car registration plates that begin with GB:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would add a GB: after the first `^`, since that's what denotes the beginning of a line.

/^GB:([A-Z]{3}\s?(\d{3}|\d{2}|d{1})\s?[A-Z])|([A-Z]\s?(\d{3}|\d{2}|\d{1})\s?[A-Z]{3})|(([A-HK-PRSVWY][A-HJ-PR-Y])\s?([0][2-9]|[1-9][0-9])\s?[A-HJ-PR-Z]{3})$/

Edit: yeah, I suppose there is a : there. Right-o.

Comment: Easy as that eh! Unfortunately when running the regular expression it's not matching the strings. If I pass in this string 'AB12 ABC GB:AB12 BCD this text should all be ignored' it just picks up 'B12 BCD'.

Answer (score 3):

`/^GB:([A-Z]{3}\s?(\d{3}|\d{2}|d{1})\s?[A-Z])|([A-Z]\s?(\d{3}|\d{2}|\d{1})\s?[A-Z]{3})|(([A-HK-PRSVWY][A-HJ-PR-Y])\s?([0][2-9]|[1-9][0-9])\s?[A-HJ-PR-Z]{3})$/`

Just make your regex say "that starts with GB: and then ..."

Answer (score 1):

The start of the statement would be:

```
^GB:([A-Z]{3}\s?(\d{3}|\d{2}|d{1})\s?[A-Z])|([A-Z]\s?(\d{3}|\d{2}|\d{1})\s?[A-Z]{3})|(([A-HK-PRSVWY][A-HJ-PR-Y])\s?([0][2-9]|[1-9][0-9])\s?[A-HJ-PR-Z]{3})$
```

The thing to remember is a statement like `[A-Z]{3}` looks for any 3 capital letters in a row, in other words, its looking for a pattern, not an exact match like you wanted.

Unless there is soemthing specific to look for after `GB:`, you could shorten it to `^GB:.*$`.

Comment: The original regular expression is for verifying UK car registration plates and does seem to work. That part of the expression is a pattern, it's only the beginning bit that should be an exact match (GB:)

Answer (score 1):

Just add "GB:", by the way you can reduce your expression: "(\d{3}|\d{2}|d{1})" with simply "(\d{1, 3})".

Comment: That depends how the regex is being used, not sure this would work in grep or a bash script.

Answer (score 1):

You *should* be able to tack `GB:` onto the front like everyone says, but there's an error in the existing regex.  It's easier to see in free-spacing mode:

```
/^([A-Z]{3} \s? \d{1,3} \s? [A-Z])
  |
  ([A-Z] \s? \d{1,3} \s? [A-Z]{3})
  |
  ([A-HK-PRSVWY][A-HJ-PR-Y] \s? (?:0[2-9]|[1-9][0-9]) \s? [A-HJ-PR-Z]{3})$
/x
```

The `^` anchor only affects the first alternative, and the `$` only affects the third one.  You have to add another layer of containment:

```
/^
 (?:
   ([A-Z]{3} \s? \d{1,3} \s? [A-Z])
   |
   ([A-Z]\s? \d{1,3} \s? [A-Z]{3})
   |
   ([A-HK-PRSVWY][A-HJ-PR-Y] \s? (?:0[2-9]|[1-9][0-9]) \s? [A-HJ-PR-Z]{3})
 )$
/x
```

...and now you can add the prefix:

```
/^
 GB:
 (?:
   ([A-Z]{3} \s? \d{1,3} \s? [A-Z])
   |
   ([A-Z]\s? \d{1,3} \s? [A-Z]{3})
   |
   ([A-HK-PRSVWY][A-HJ-PR-Y] \s? (?:0[2-9]|[1-9][0-9]) \s? [A-HJ-PR-Z]{3})
 )$
/x
```

...or in line-noise mode:

```
/^GB:(?:([A-Z]{3}\s?\d{1,3}\s?[A-Z])|([A-Z]\s?\d{1,3}\s?[A-Z]{3})|([A-HK-PRSVWY][A-HJ-PR-Y]\s?(?:0[2-9]|[1-9][0-9])\s?[A-HJ-PR-Z]{3}))$/
```