# Checking if a string fits a pattern

Tags: python, string

Hi I need to check if a string fits a pattern in python. The pattern in question is that of a standard UK car registration. The pattern is

- two Letters
- two Numbers
- a space
- three Letters

For example

```
AB56 TYR
```

How can I get a program to check if the registration that the user has input matches this pattern?

Comment: Write a regular expression. check if its matching.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of regular expression ! `import re`, and enjoy :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Ideally, we prefer questions to include [an example of the source code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in order to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com). Please consider including this information in your post.

Comment: The description you made of car registration codes is not accurate. See at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_registration_plates_of_the_United_Kingdom,_Crown_dependencies_and_overseas_territories#Current_system

Comment: [Older number plates use an `A123ABC` pattern instead](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/57/British_car_number_plates.jpg).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re
if re.match(r'^[A-Z][A-Z]\d\d [A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]$', text):
    # valid
```

Comment: I've added the missing space.

Comment: Although it's not in the question, the UK car registration doesn't use every letter from the alphabet so the above answer will still recognise invalid registrations. See [this page on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_registration_plates_of_the_United_Kingdom,_Crown_dependencies_and_overseas_territories#Characters).

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i Came up with

```
 import re
    text = 'AB56 TYR'
    text2='Adfsdf56 TYR'
    m = re.search('^([A-Z]{3}\s?(\d{3}|\d{2}|d{1})\s?[A-Z])|([A-Z]\s?(\d{3}|\d{2}|\d{1})\s?[A-Z]{3})|(([A-HK-PRSVWY][A-HJ-PR-Y])\s?([0][2-9]|[1-9][0-9])\s?[A-HJ-PR-Z]{3})', text)
    n = re.search('^([A-Z]{3}\s?(\d{3}|\d{2}|d{1})\s?[A-Z])|([A-Z]\s?(\d{3}|\d{2}|\d{1})\s?[A-Z]{3})|(([A-HK-PRSVWY][A-HJ-PR-Y])\s?([0][2-9]|[1-9][0-9])\s?[A-HJ-PR-Z]{3})', text2)
    if m:
        print "NUMBER IS GOOD"
    else:
        print "BAD NUMBER"

    if n:
        print "NUMBER IS GOOD"
    else:
        print "BAD NUMBER"
```

Comment: That looks mighty complicated. Are you sure it is correct?

Comment: Well, it's not a real regex unless it looks like line noise. :)

Comment: Probably there are so many optimization needed. Atleast let him do the optimization i thought. Copy paste wont make a good programmer right? :D

And it as per my knowledge UK number have a specific set of Alphabets for a part

Comment: The OP asked about a description where any letter is valid as an identification code. You answered a more restricted (thought realistic) case. I'm not the downvoter but that might be the case.

Comment: Anyway let the moderator decide. Thanks Paco

Comment: @AbhilashCherukat: "copy paste won't make a good programmer" - ah, the irony! That regex looks very like the one on [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7046646/regular-expression-trouble). However, I will say that this regex does at least attempt to cater for the more specific UK registration plates as you say. Certainly nothing to warrant a downvote in my opinion.

Comment: @elParaguayo: True I took it net like we all do. but i would say we will change according to our need. Why waste time to re-write the entire script. We all learn from the code others wrote,but by working on it. And i made sure it works before posting :D

Actually i took it from here http://regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=617